# How to start at a specific index in the range?

Tags: python

The program must print out n + 41 as 6 rows of 7 numbers, the first row will be n + 6, the second will be n + 7 to n + 7 + 6 and so on.

```
n = int(input('Enter number between -6 between 2: '))

if -6 <= n <= 2:
  for x in range(n, 37, 7):
    for r in range(x,  x + 7):
        print("{:>2}".format(r), end=" ")
    print()

else:
  print("Wrong input!!")
```

Sample Output for -2 is:

5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
26 27 28 29 30 31 32 
33 34 35 36 37 38 39

Comment: You mean you want to use different values in the first `range()` loop if the input is -2?

Comment: Does not really make sense what you are trying to achieve. Just for reference `range` works as follows`range(start, end, step)`

Comment: `list(range(5, 39))`? is that all you're looking for?

Comment: Change to: `for x in range(n+7, 37, 7):` ?

Comment: Your question needs more clarification, so others can understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. It skips the first 7 numbers but checking to see if x in the range is equal to the input value. If it is, is restarts the loop and continues from there.

```
n = int(input('Enter number between -6 between 2: '))

if -6 <= n <= 2:
  for x in range(n, 37, 7):
    if x == n:
          continue
    for r in range(x,  x + 7):
      print("{:>2}".format(r), end=" ")

else:
  print("Wrong input!!")
```

Output:

```
5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print from 5 and end at 39 if the input value is -2 then this will work for you,

```
n = int(input('Enter number between -6 between 2: '))

if -6 <= n <= 2:
  for x in range(n, 37, 7):
    for r in range(x,  x + 7):
        print("{:>2}".format(r), end=" ")
    print()

else:
  print("Wrong input!!")
```

output:

```
Enter number between -6 between 2: -2
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
26 27 28 29 30 31 32 
33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```